# (Qt)SQL: How to use bind values within quotes?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I'm trying to use user input inside a `MATCH` clause, but it looks like `?`s inside quotes are ignored;
I'm working with `QtSql`:

```py
>>> from PySide6 import QtSql as sql
>>> database = sql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
>>> database.setDatabaseName("db.db")
>>> database.open()
True
>>> query = sql.QSqlQuery("""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableFTS5 WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH 'source : ?' AND source_id = ?""", database)
>>> query.addBindValue("website")
>>> query.addBindValue(1608)
>>> query.exec()
False
>>> query.lastError()
<PySide6.QtSql.QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "") at 0x7f5ded89b500>
>>> query = sql.QSqlQuery("""SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableFTS5 WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH 'source : "website"' AND source_id = ?""", database)
>>> query.addBindValue(1608)
>>> query.exec()
True
```

thinking it could be something specific to `QtSql`, I also tried it with `sqlite3` but got the same result:

```py
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
>>> conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableFTS5 WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH 'source : ?' AND source_id = ?", ("website", "1608"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
>>> conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableFTS5 WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH 'source : website' AND source_id = ?", ("1608", ))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fa99cda3a40>
```

How would I use bind values in this case?

EDIT1:
Found a "workaround" but is this the only way to do it?

```py
>>> conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableFTS5 WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH 'source : ' + ? AND source_id=?", ("website", 1608))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f7bd22eba40>
```

EDIT2:
EDIT1 does not work with bind values. The query is grammatically correct, but not the same as `MATCH 'source : website'`.

Comment: I've never used `MATCH`, but as far as I can see it uses parentheses. Why do you need quotes? The value binding should take care of value syntax on its own.

Comment: @musicamante , can I ask where you saw it being used with parentheses? Because as far as I can see the argument to `MATCH` needs to be a string: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html . I get `unrecognized token: ":"` when trying `MATCH (source : "website")` in plain SQL.

Comment: I was basing on the default SQL implementation (as far as I can understand, fts5 overrides the default behavior: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html ). For what I can see, that's not standard SQL syntax, so it seems that you need a workaround anyway (text inside quotes is not evaluated for placeholders, as it's assumed as a static content, just like a hardcoded value). By the way, did you try to just *not* use quotes? (Might seem a dumb question, but, as said, I never used it)

Comment: @musicamante >not use quotes; yeah, got the same error.

Comment: The MATCH operator requires an FTS query in the form of a string. You cannot embed SQL parameters in a string. Therefore, you must do something like `query.addBindValue('source : "website"')` and then `WHERE TableFTS5 MATCH ? AND source_id = ?`. FTS queries use specialised syntax which must be parsed separately by the extension.

Comment: Didn't think about using the whole match query as the bind value; it worked, thank you, @ekhumoro .